# Acumatica PXLabel Visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I have a control

```
<px:PXLabel runat="server" ID="edWeekType" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" Text="Weeks"/>
```

I need to hide it according to a vaule in one of the fields value in the DAC or property in the Graph.
[image]
I mean, if code behind can control visibility of a control if it is not bound to a property in DAC?

```
                    <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule7" StartRow="True" runat="server" Merge="true" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" />
                    <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" DataField="NumberOfHours" ID="edNumberOfHours" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXLabel runat="server" ID="edHourUnit" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" Text="Hours"/>

                    <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule8" StartRow="True" runat="server" Merge="true" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" />
                    <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" DataField="NumberOfDays" ID="edNumberOfDays" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXLabel runat="server" ID="edDayEdit" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" Text="Days"/>

                    <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule9" StartRow="True" runat="server" Merge="true" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" />
                    <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" DataField="NumberOfWeeks" ID="edNumberOfWeeks" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXLabel runat="server" ID="edWeekType" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" Text="Weeks" />
```

All objects `px:PXLayoutRule` already controlled by appropriate DataField ( for example `DataField="NumberOfHours"`), but `px:PXLabel` are not bound.

Can I show/hide labels that are not bound? Is that possible?

Comment: Not possible to hide unbound controls from the BLC (graph) layer. A workaround is to create a TextEdit control styled like a label, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a TextEdit control styled to look like a label with a merge layout rule to keep field and fake label on same row.

```
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True"  Merge="True" />
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edLabel" runat="server" DataField="Label" SuppressLabel="True" SkinID="Label" Style="pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.7;" />
<px:PXSelector ID="edField" runat="server" DataField="Field" SuppressLabel="True" />
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True"/>
```

SuppresLabel property is used to hide the automatic label control that is appended to fields. Because the solution is using a `TextEdit` control (styled to look like a label) instead of a `Label` control the text value will be bound to the DAC field specified and you can assign text value from the graph. You will also be able to call SetVisible method on the fake label for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Hugues Beauséjour, it looks like I need to bind it to a DAC field anyway. Right?

Comment: That would be the best option to hide the field, using PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible.

Comment: So there is no pretty way to hide it like in WPF and the way I did it is only option.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: It is recommended to put logic in the graph, label can't be bounded so pretty or not it can't be accessed from graph.

Answer (score 0):

When I waited to proper Acumatica solution, I implemented my own with option to change it to better one if it will be posted later.

I defined non-db fields in the DAC:

```
  #region UnitsHours
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Hours", Enabled = false)]
    [PXDefault("Hours")]
    public string UnitsHours { get; set; }
    public abstract class unitsHours : IBqlField { }
    #endregion


    #region UnitsDays
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Days", Enabled = false)]
    [PXDefault("Days")]
    public string UnitsDays { get; set; }
    public abstract class unitsDays : IBqlField { }
    #endregion


    #region UnitsWeeks
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Weeks", Enabled = false)]
    [PXDefault("Weeks")]
    public string UnitsWeeks { get; set; }
    public abstract class unitsWeeks : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #endregion
```

I enable/disable it in graph when needed:

```
// Graph code:
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<MPLeaveRequest.unitsDays>(this.LeaveRequests.Cache, null, myBooleanProperty1);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<MPLeaveRequest.unitsWeeks>(this.LeaveRequests.Cache, null, myBooleanProperty1);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<MPLeaveRequest.unitsHours>(this.LeaveRequests.Cache, null, myBooleanProperty1);
```

and ASPX code:

```
  <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule7" StartRow="True" runat="server" Merge="true" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" />
  <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" DataField="NumberOfHours" ID="edNumberOfHours" CommitChanges="true" />
  <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="edHourUnit" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" DataField="UnitsHours"/>

   <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule8" StartRow="True" runat="server" Merge="true" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" />
   <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" DataField="NumberOfDays" ID="edNumberOfDays" CommitChanges="true" />
   <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="edDayEdit" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" DataField="UnitsDays"/>

   <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule9" StartRow="True" runat="server" Merge="true" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" />
   <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" DataField="NumberOfWeeks" ID="edNumberOfWeeks" CommitChanges="true" />
   <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="edWeekType" SuppressLabel="true" Width="130px" DataField="UnitsWeeks" />
```

So I achieved the target I wanted, however, not in the way I wanted. Hopefully it will he helpful to someone.